# ZF2 - Rendering variables from Module.php to twig layout

Tags: variables, layout, module, zend-framework2, twig

I'm in the midst of converting a ZF2 site from using default templates into twig versions, and so far, for the main part, everything is going well, except I have some variables in Module.php defined from a bootstrap method that I'm now unable to get into the layout.twig template.

The original code that worked fine for the default templates is as:

```
public function bootstrapLayout(MvcEvent $e)
{
    $config = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('applicationconfig');
    $authService = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('AuthService');

    $version = new \stdClass();
    $version->major = $config['version']['major'];
    $version->minor = $config['version']['minor'];

    $dt = new \DateTime();

    $thisYear = $dt->format('Y');

    $dt->setTimestamp($config['version']['build_date']);
    $version->buildDate = $dt->format('d/m/Y H:i');

    $user = new \stdClass();
    $user->hasIdentity = $authService->hasIdentity();
    $user->username = $authService->getStorage()->read('username');

    $e->getViewModel()->setVariables(array(
        'version' => $version,
        'thisYear' => $thisYear,
        'user' => $user,
    ));
}
```

However, neither 'version', 'thisYear' nor 'user' make itself known to the twig layout template. I've searched on here and the closest resolution I came to finding was to obtain the ZfcTwigRenderer by:

```
$zfcTwigRenderer = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('ZfcTwigRenderer');
```

but now I'm at a loss how I can utilise this and pass my defined vars through it to the layout.

Here's the content of the layout file:

```
{{ docType() }}
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>{% block title %}{% endblock title %} - Website</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        {% block meta %}{% endblock meta %}

        <!-- Le styles -->
        <link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="/css/bootstrap-hidden-inline.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="/css/theme.min.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="/css/style.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon">
        {% block style %}{% endblock style %}

        <!-- Scripts -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/tooltip.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
        <!--[if lt IE 9]><script type="text/javascript" src="/js/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/modernizr.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/overlays.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/common.min.js"></script>
        {% block script %}{% endblock script %}
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    {% if user.hasIdentity %}
                        <button class="navbar-toggle" data-target=".navbar-collapse" data-toggle="collapse" type="button">
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                    {% endif %}
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url('home') }}">Website</a>
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <!--<li><a class="icon-home" href="{{ url('home') }}"><span></span>Home</a></li>-->
                        {% if user.hasIdentity %}
                            <li class="hidden-sm hidden-xs"><a class="icon-import" href="{{ url('import') }}"><span></span>Import</a></li>
                            <li class="hidden-sm hidden-xs"><a class="icon-export" href="{{ url('export') }}"><span></span>Export</a></li>
                            <li><a class="icon-about" href="{{ url('about') }}"><span></span>About</a></li>
                            <!-- <li><a class="icon-reports" href="#"><span></span>Reports</a></li> -->
                            <li><a class="icon-logout" href="{{ url('logout') }}"><span></span>Logout</a></li>
                        {% endif %}
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        {% if user.hasIdentity %}
                            <!--<li><a class="icon-report-bug" href="{{ url('report-bug') }}"><span></span>Report bug</a></li>-->
                        {% endif %}
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% if user.hasIdentity %}
            <div class="container hidden-sm hidden-xs">
                <div class="welcome-message"><span></span>Welcome {{ user.username }}</div>
            </div>
        {% endif %}
        <div class="container">
            {% block content %}{{ content|raw }}{% endblock content %}
            <hr>
            <footer>
                Copyright &copy; {{ thisYear }} Company name<br>
                Version {{ version.major }}.{{ version.minor }} &mdash;
                Build {{ version.buildDate }}
            </footer>
        </div> <!-- /container -->
        {% block inline %}{% endblock inline %}
    </body>
</html>
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated as I've really come up against a dead end, despite trying all sorts of things for the past couple of hours.

Comment: I'm assuming you are using `{% extends "layout/layout" %}` syntax to choose the layout?

Comment: I am for my main view templates, but it's the actual layout I want to get the variables into from the boostrap (getting the variables into the main views is working as expected). I've added my layout.twig code above too to hopefully clarify a bit more on where I'm looking to access the variables from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For true global variables that are available inside all layouts you need to do the following inside a onBootstrap function in Module.php so you example would be

```
public function bootstrapLayout(MvcEvent $e)
{
    $config = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('applicationconfig');
    $authService = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('AuthService');

    $version = new \stdClass();
    $version->major = $config['version']['major'];
    $version->minor = $config['version']['minor'];

    $dt = new \DateTime();

    $thisYear = $dt->format('Y');

    $dt->setTimestamp($config['version']['build_date']);
    $version->buildDate = $dt->format('d/m/Y H:i');

    $user = new \stdClass();
    $user->hasIdentity = $authService->hasIdentity();
    $user->username = $authService->getStorage()->read('username');

    $enviroment = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('ZfcTwigEnvironment');
    $enviroment->addGlobal('version', $version);
    $enviroment->addGlobal('thisYear', $thisYear);
    $enviroment->addGlobal('user', $user);
}
```

This would then allow you to use your above template like you have set out.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks Tom, this is just the ticket! Works perfectly.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help. This took me a while to work out when I needed to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
current ($e->getViewModel ()->getChildren ())->setVariables(array(
    'version' => $version,
    'thisYear' => $thisYear,
    'user' => $user,
));
```

instead of

```
$e->getViewModel()->setVariables(array(
    'version' => $version,
    'thisYear' => $thisYear,
    'user' => $user,
));
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion akond, but this throws an error: `Fatal error: Call to a member function setVariables() on a non-object in /path/module/Application/Module.php on line 163`

Comment: That is very interesting, because it works in my case. I wonder what your configuration is?

Answer (score -1):

Ahah! After a bit more digging around on the net for ZF2 concepts in general, I've managed to come up with a solution. Maybe, maybe not, the best, but it's working (at least for now)... the solution was a custom view helper.

In *Module.php*, I added a `getViewHelperConfig()` method that I plan to call via `globalVars()`:

```
public function getViewHelperConfig()
{
    return array(
        'factories' => array(
            'globalVars' => function($helperPluginManager) {
                    $serviceLocator = $helperPluginManager->getServiceLocator();
                    $viewHelper = new View\Helper\GlobalVars();
                    $viewHelper->setServiceLocator($serviceLocator);
                    return $viewHelper;
                }
        ),
    );
}
```

Then I created the view helper in *Application\src\Application\View\Helper\GlobalVars.php*:

```
<?php
namespace Application\View\Helper;

use Zend\View\Helper\AbstractHelper;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager;

class GlobalVars extends AbstractHelper
{
    protected $serviceLocator;

    public function __invoke()
    {
        $config = $this->serviceLocator->get('applicationconfig');
        $authService = $this->serviceLocator->get('AuthService');

        $dateTime = new \DateTime();
        $date = new \stdClass();
        $date->thisYear = $dateTime->format('Y');

        $dateTime->setTimestamp($config['version']['build_date']);

        $version = new \stdClass();
        $version->major = $config['version']['major'];
        $version->minor = $config['version']['minor'];
        $version->buildDate = $dateTime->format('d/m/Y H:i');

        $user = new \stdClass();
        $user->hasIdentity = $authService->hasIdentity();
        $user->username = $authService->getStorage()->read('username');

        return array(
            'version' => $version,
            'date' => $date,
            'user' => $user,
        );
    }

    public function setServiceLocator(ServiceManager $serviceLocator)
    {
        $this->serviceLocator = $serviceLocator;
    }
}
```

In *layout.twig*, I now call this via `{{ globalVars().version.major }}` for example, and to check whether the user is logged in or not, `{% if globalVars().user.hasIdentity %}`.

If someone has a better / more elegant method, then I'd most certainly be interested in seeing it, but if not, or if this is the "best" approach, then hopefully it'll be useful for others too.

Comment: I think you're on the right track with view helpers, but why load all the variables into one "global" helper? Make a helper per data type, and rather than injecting the service locator, inject the specific data type(s) you need. This would make it more readable, and testable.