# how to get the request URI in zf2 twig?

Tags: zend-framework2, twig

I want to get the full URI address of the current page in twig page in zf2. if I use url() it will only return back the zend url not the full adress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution on the top is a good solution to have customized global variables in twig for zf2 but to the specific problem I have I found the solution:

```
{{serverUrl(true)}}
```

the parameter true was what I was missing to get the full url.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using a custom framework (similar as Symfony2). The way I handle this kind of things is by creating global twig variables inside the constructor of my controller. Take a look at this [ZF2 - Rendering variables from Module.php to twig layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20272214/zf2-rendering-variables-from-module-php-to-twig-layout).